# ESP8266 - Device doesn't support that

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I'm using and trying the new Echo Dot generation (3rd Gen) to control a ESP8266 following some tutorials. For now I just want to change the state of a relay using the `SetBinaryState` action. But after discovering the device, if I try to turn it on, I get the **"Device doesn't support that"** response.

The tutorials I've found are for the previous generations, and the packets seem to be different, as I had to fix something in the discovery process. But I can't figure out where's the problem when setting the state as I haven't seen any documentation related to this. This is the `setup.xml`

```
"<serviceList>"
    "<service>"
        "<serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1</serviceType>"
        "<serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:basicevent1</serviceId>"
        "<controlURL>/upnp/control/basicevent1</controlURL>"
        "<eventSubURL>/upnp/event/basicevent1</eventSubURL>"
        "<SCPDURL>/eventservice.xml</SCPDURL>"
    "</service>"
"</serviceList>"
```

And these are the logs that I'm getting:

```
Received packet of size 94
From 192.168.1.3, port 50000
Request:
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
Host: 239.255.255.250:1900
Man: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 3
ST: ssdp:all


Responding to search request ...

Sending response to 192.168.1.3
Port : 50000
Response sent!

Received packet of size 101
From 192.168.1.3, port 50000
Request:
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
Host: 239.255.255.250:1900
Man: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 3
ST: upnp:rootdevice


Responding to search request ...

Sending response to 192.168.1.3
Port : 50000
Response sent!

Responding to setup.xml ...
Sending :<?xml version="1.0"?><root><device><deviceType>urn:Belkin:device:controllee:1</deviceType><friendlyName>Living room light</friendlyName><manufacturer>Belkin International Inc.</manufacturer><modelName>Emulated Socket</modelName><modelNumber>3.1415</modelNumber><UDN>uuid:Socket-1_0-38323636-4558-4dda-9188-cda0e616a12b</UDN><serialNumber>221517K0101769</serialNumber><binaryState>0</binaryState><serviceList><service><serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1</serviceType><serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:basicevent1</serviceId><controlURL>/upnp/control/basicevent1</controlURL><eventSubURL>/upnp/event/basicevent1</eventSubURL><SCPDURL>/eventservice.xml</SCPDURL></service></serviceList></device></root>

Responding to  /upnp/control/basicevent1...
Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:GetBinaryState xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1"><BinaryState>1</BinaryState></u:GetBinaryState></s:Body></s:Envelope>

Responding to  /upnp/control/basicevent1...
Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:GetBinaryState xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1"><BinaryState>1</BinaryState></u:GetBinaryState></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

And then tons of these packets:

```
Received packet of size 278
From 192.168.1.1, port 1900
Request:
NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1 
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=3000
Location: http://192.168.1.1:5431/igdevicedesc.xml
SERVER: Router UPnP/1.0 miniupnpd
NT: uuid:f5c1d177-62e5-45d1-a6e7-9446962b761e
USN: uuid:f5c1d177-62e5-45d1-a6e7-9446962b76
```

One thing I've noticed is that the `eventservice.xml` never gets called, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling around I figure out that it looks like you have to send the device state after every `SetBinaryState` request.

So, if the ESP node receives a `SetBinaryState` command, it will have to answer with a `GetBinaryState`.

```
void Light::_handleCommands()
{
  Serial.println("Responding to /upnp/control/basicevent...1");      

  String request = server->arg(0); 

  if (request.indexOf("SetBinaryState") >= 0) 
  {
    if (request.indexOf("<BinaryState>1</BinaryState>") >= 0) 
    {
        Serial.println(" - Got Turn on request");
        lightStatus= turnOnLight();

        sendLightStatus();
    }

    if (request.indexOf("<BinaryState>0</BinaryState>") >= 0) 
    {
        Serial.println(" - Got Turn off request");
        lightStatus= turnOffLight();

        sendLightStatus();
    }
  }

  if (request.indexOf("GetBinaryState") >= 0) 
  {
    Serial.println(" - Got light state request");

    sendLightStatus();
  }

  server->send(200, "text/plain", "");
}
```

On top of that, it looks that the response has to 'make sense', ie. if a Turn On request is received, it has to return '1' in the `GetBinaryState`. Else Alexa will say that the device is not responding or it's malfunctioning.